# How to send new form fields with data from Django views.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, field

I am adding a new field named "user" to the "order" model. I did make migrations.
(Bonus question is: why in the sql3db column "user_id" was made, instead of "user"? But ok, I change form.fields['user'] to form.fields['user_id'], as the machine wants...)

I remove unneeded fields from the form in forms.py, and I try to add this fields in views.py (because I don't know how to send "user" to the forms.py, and I think it more secure like this).

And as I can understand - my new fields is absent for "order", when I use form.save().
This field can't be null by design.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should use `user` everywhere, not `user_id`. The "_id" suffix is used to access the raw value of the ForeignKey, usually the id of the related object, but you rarely need to access this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no `user` field, hence that will not work. What you can do is alter the object wrapped in the form with:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = request.user
    form.instance.email = request.user.email
    order = form.save()
```